# how to install ansible on rhel 8 /centos 8?

Tags: ansible

I want to install ansible in RHEL 8 Centos. 
To use yum install ansible i must enable epel release but i can't find a best source of epel release for Rhel 8.

**I tried this**

```
sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install ansible
```

**The output i got is**

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:26 ago on Sun 11 Aug 2019 12:21:55 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python-setuptools needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-jinja2 needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python-six needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides PyYAML needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides python2-cryptography needed by ansible-2.8.2-1.el7.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPEL8 is not released yet. There are some packages available, but a lot are still being worked on and the repo is not considered "generally available".

For now, you can install Ansible from the Python Package Index (PyPI):

```
yum install python3-pip
pip3 install ansible
```

Comment: ansible 2.8.3
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jun 12 2019, 01:12:31) [GCC 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3)]

Comment: ansible got installed but the problem now is I don't have a config file in my etc/ansible/ 
you can see the above output of ansible --version gave which says config file = None

Comment: The supplied global config is one of the "niceties" of the packaged ansible rpm. You can either create it yourself, or use a local ansible.cfg. Have a look at `ansible-config dump` for a list of the defaults - this will get you started on what you need to override in your config.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using RHEL 8 then you can use the subscription manager to get Ansible with the host and config file pre-built.

Also, you will need to create an account on https://developers.redhat.com before you can do this:

```
subscription-manager register --auto-attach

subscription-manager repos --enable ansible-2.8-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms

yum -y install ansible

ansible --version
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for RHEL9 Should work for RHEL8 as well

```
[root@controller yum.repos.d]# yum list | grep  ansible
ansible-collection-microsoft-sql.noarch              1.1.1-3.el9_0                      Local-AppStream
    ansible-collection-redhat-rhel_mgmt.noarch           1.0.0-2.el9                        Local-AppStream
    ansible-core.x86_64                                  2.12.2-1.el9                       Local-AppStream
    ansible-freeipa.noarch                               1.6.3-1.el9                        Local-AppStream
    ansible-freeipa-tests.noarch                         1.6.3-1.el9                        Local-AppStream
    ansible-pcp.noarch                                   2.2.2-2.el9                        Local-AppStream
    ansible-test.x86_64                                  2.12.2-1.el9                       Local-AppStream
[root@controller yum.repos.d]# yum install ansible-core.x86_64
```